# How do I get the second largest element from an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an integer array like this :

```
arr[20,120,111,215,54,78];
```

I need a function taking an array as its argument and returning the second largest element of that array.

Comment: Note: that's *not* an integer array, that's a string array. You may end up with "unexpected" results if you compare those elements incorrectly, as strings use lexical ordering. For example, `'20' < '120' === false` whereas `20 < 120 === true`.

Comment: I found this(http://www.ajaybadgujar.com/finding-second-largest-number-from-array-in-javascript/) solution very useful  with minimal complexity

Comment: `function processData(myArray) {
    var setArray = Array.from(new Set(myArray)).sort((a, b) => a - b)
    return setArray[setArray.length - 2] || myArray[0];
}`

Comment: One of the simplest solution is:- arr = [20,120,111,215,54,78]; let secondLargest = arr.sort(function(x,y) { return y-x} )[1]; And if you want to go for traditional way;- arr = [20,120,111,215,54,78]; max=arr[0] max2=arr[0] for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) { if(max < arr[i]) { max2 = max; max = arr[i]; } else if(max2 < arr[i]) { max2 = arr[i]; } } console.log(max: ${max} and max2: ${max2});

Comment: Since this question is closed I can only add the answer as comment. Sorry
Answer goes here --->
    let getSecondLargeNumber = function(nums)
    {
        nums.sort((a,b)=>b-a);
        let biggestNumber = nums[0];
        let secondLargeNumber = nums.find(element => element < biggestNumber);

        if (secondLargeNumber == undefined)
        {
            secondLargeNumber = 0;
        }

        console.log('biggestNumber: ' + biggestNumber);
        console.log('secondLargeNumber: ' + secondLargeNumber);

        return secondLargeNumber;
    }

Answer (score 49, accepted):

## Original answer

```
var secondMax = function (){ 
    var arr = [20, 120, 111, 215, 54, 78]; // use int arrays
    var max = Math.max.apply(null, arr); // get the max of the array
    arr.splice(arr.indexOf(max), 1); // remove max from the array
    return Math.max.apply(null, arr); // get the 2nd max
};
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/evepip/1/edit)

## Update 1

As pointed out by **davin** the performance could be enhanced by not doing a splice but *temporarily* replacing the max value with `-Infininty`:

```
var secondMax = function (arr){ 
    var max = Math.max.apply(null, arr), // get the max of the array
        maxi = arr.indexOf(max);
    arr[maxi] = -Infinity; // replace max in the array with -infinity
    var secondMax = Math.max.apply(null, arr); // get the new max 
    arr[maxi] = max;
    return secondMax;
};
```

Anyway, IMHO the best algorithm is Jack's. 1 pass, with conversion to number.
Mine is just short, using builtin methods and only wanted to provide it as an alternative, to show off all the different ways you can achieve the goal.

## Update 2

Edge case with multiple values.

As comments pointed it out: this solution "does not work" if we have an array like `[3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4]`.
On the other hand it would be also a matter of interpretation what we would consider "the 2nd largest element".
In the example we have:

1. 3 elements with the largest value (5) at indices: 2,3,4
2. 2 elements with the second largest value (4) at indices: 5,6
3. 2 elements with the second smallest value (3) at indices: 1,2

The 2nd largest element could be interpreted as:

1. the 2nd (largest element) - 5 at index 3 - assuming that there is an order, and that we aim for a unique value
2. the (2nd largest) element - 4 at index 5 - assuming that there is an order, and that we aim for a unique value

Comment: The only correct `O(n)` solution as of now.

Comment: @davin It modifies the array though.

Comment: @Jack, easily overcome by inplace replacement with `-Infinity` and then restoration. This would also be faster and ensure all-round `O(1)` space complexity, as opposed to other methods that use `O(n)` space.

Comment: @davin I wouldn't call that an improvement ... you have seen *my* answer though, right? :) the `-Infinity` is a good point though ..

Comment: @Jack, you wouldn't call it an improvement? Since when is saving time and space and maintaining the input not an improvement?

Comment: it would also "*fail*" on a list like `[5,3,20,9,20]`.

Comment: The modifying of the array issue can be fixed if you defined the array outside the function and then had the function take in an array argument and that argument would equal the var arr. It also fails on duplicates as jAndy pointed out, but that's an easy fix. I'll play around with it some more and see if I can come up with something better.

Comment: I found this(http://www.ajaybadgujar.com/finding-second-largest-number-from-array-in-javascript/) solution very useful  with minimal complexity

Comment: One of the simplest solution is:- 
`arr = [20,120,111,215,54,78];

 let secondLargest = arr.sort(function(x,y) { return y-x} )[1];`

 And if you want to go for traditional way;-

`arr = [20,120,111,215,54,78];
max=arr[0]
max2=arr[0]

for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if(max < arr[i]) {
        max2 = max;
        max = arr[i];
    } else if(max2 < arr[i]) {
        max2 = arr[i];
    }
}

console.log(`max: ${max} and max2: ${max2}`);`

Comment: This is another way which I think more efficient and better than yours.
`function getSecondLargest(nums) {
    let arr = Array.from(new Set(nums.sort(function(a, b){return(b-a)})))
    let second = arr[1]

    return second
}`

Comment: Depends how you defined efficiency: memory allocation / array iterations etc. 
In your case complexity is: `n * log(n) (sort) + n (construct set) + n' (construct array of unique nrs)`
in my case: `n (max) + n (indexOf) + n(max)` which depending on n is computationally less expensive and does not need new memory allocations (disregarding temporary local variables)

Comment: This is another simple way to find second largest number of an array:
function getSecondLargest(nums) {
  let uniqueNum = [...new Set(nums)];
  let numsOrder = uniqueNum.sort((a,b) => b-a);
  return numsOrder[1];
}

console.log(getSecondLargest([2,3,6,6,5]));

Comment: Yes the above fails if you have duplicate largest elements in the aray

Comment: Yes, this won't work when elements repeat.

Answer (score 60):

The most straightforward implementation, without modifying the original array, is to iterate and track the biggest and next biggest:

```js
function nextBiggest(arr) {
  let max = -Infinity, result = -Infinity;

  for (const value of arr) {
    const nr = Number(value)

    if (nr > max) {
      [result, max] = [max, nr] // save previous max
    } else if (nr < max && nr > result) {
      result = nr; // new second biggest
    }
  }

  return result;
}

const arr = ['20','120','111','215','54','78'];
console.log(nextBiggest(arr));
```

### Variations

The behaviour of returning `-Infinity` if there's no next maximum value distinct from the maximum value in a non-empty array can be modified at the end of the function, depending on the requirements.

#### Same as maximum

```js
return result == -Infinity ? max : result;
```

For an empty array, this will return `-Infinity` as before, but would otherwise return the same value as the maximum if no next distinct maximum is found.

#### Return null

```js
return result == -Infinity ? null : result;
```

Same as above, but the return value of `null` is more indicative of the nonexistence of a next distinct maximum.

Comment: +1 I'm amazed that for 15 minutes people were sorting arrays instead of just performing a single pass.

Comment: this also has its *problems* with two equal "highest values". I guess its still a question of definition, but any algo on this requirement should return `5` for a `[5,10,10]` list.

Comment: @jAndy Thanks for spotting that obvious oversight :) fixed.

Comment: @davin Most often, in JavaScript, you don't really care if your code takes 10 ms instead of 3 ms but you care about the simplicity of your application. I don't say this is a bad answer, it's good, but the performance preoccupation in comments here is probably exaggerated.

Comment: @Ja͢ck could someone maybe explain to me how this works? Sorry, might sound stupid.

`if (nr > biggest)` should always be true on the first run. Then your setting `next_biggest = biggest` but `next_biggest` is declared as `-Infinity` in the global scope. How does this work?

Comment: @PourMeSomeCode sorry for the late reply ... if an array either has only one element, or all values are the same, then there's technically no "next biggest" value to speak of; hence the declaration ... hope that makes sense :)

Comment: This code returns -Infinity if array values are all same [1,1,1,1,1,1] . Just a note

Comment: @JayanthKumarT well, technically the second biggest number is indeed `-Infinity` :)

Comment: In my opinion, the correct result for the case in which all values are the same is not `-Infinity`, in this case, the result would be one of the values in the list. Because, the algorithm is supposed to find the second largest number in a given list, not something outside the list. Just like what `Math.max()` does in this case! Hence, I think it would be better to change the `else if` condition to `(nr <= max && nr > result)`.

Comment: @MostafaFakhraei what if the array is empty, then? depending on the requirements adjustments can be made to the outcome, but it doesn’t change the base algorithm; another option is to return`null` to indicate that there is no second largest

Comment: @Ja͢ck If the array is empty then the result would be `-Infinity`. The current algorithm is perfect. However, I would expect the result for some cases to be close to `Math.max`. As you know, in the case of an array with all same values, `Math.max()` returns one of values. and in case of an empty array, `Math.max` returns `-Infinity`. The only difference is in the case of the equal values, which I suggested be more extended.

Comment: @MostafaFakhraei the behaviour of `Math.max` is like that, because in a non-empty there must necessarily always be a maximum value; but the same doesn't hold for the next distinct maximum value ... that said, i've modified the answer to include variations.

Answer (score 23):

The simplest solution is to sort :

```
// here's your array :
var stringArray = new Array('20','120','111','215','54','78');

// let's convert it to a real array of numbers, not of strings :
var intArray = stringArray.map(Number);

// now let's sort it and take the second element :
var second = intArray.sort(function(a,b){return b-a})[1];
```

If you don't want the simplest but the fastest (you probably don't need it), then you'd have to write your `for` loop and store the two greatest elements while looping.

Comment: +1 for `.map( Number );` <3

Comment: If your looking for compliance with older browsers you will need to provide an implementation of map:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: This will fail if there are two same numbers in the list.

Comment: @HarryBomrah no, it won't fail, or you have a uncommon vision of the goal.

Comment: +1 For not modifying the original array, albeit with a memory sacrifice :)

Comment: @Jack Obviously if performances are needed, your code would be the best one.

Comment: @dystroy I think Harry meant that if there are two values of `'215'` it would give the wrong second biggest.

Comment: @DenysSéguret will not work for input like->  ['20','120','111','215','54','54']

Comment: In case of duplicate items in array, we can use "filter" method of array. 
With ES6 -> 
return arr.sort((a,b) => b-a).filter((v,i,a) => a.indexOf(v) === i)[1];

Comment: just do `intArray = [...new Set(intArray)];` before sort if there are duplicates.

Comment: @HenrikhKantuni. adding more space complexity

Answer (score 8):

First sort it backwards and then get the second element:

```
['20','120','111','215','54','78'].sort(function(a, b) { return b - a; })[1];
// '120'
```

Obviously works with strings too.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that converting to numbers isn't strictly needed for sorting.

Comment: @dystroy, the cast is strictly needed, it isn't explicitly needed. This method does convert to `Number`, just it does so implicitly.

Comment: @davin I know, of course, I was speaking of the addition of an intermediate step.

Comment: this will fail when there is repeated number in array eg. [2, 3, 6, 6, 5] expected output is 5 but you will get 6 with this line of code

Comment: For duplicate values in array this isn't passing the intended algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Sort the array and then return the second index.

```
var arr = ['20','120','111','215','54','78'];

arr.sort(function(a,b){
    return b-a;
});

console.log(arr[1]);
```

Comment: This will fail if there are duplicate items in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Sort your array from smallest to largest, then grab second one from the end with `.length-2`

```js
var myArray =['20','120','111','215','54','78'];
var secondLargest = myArray.sort(function(a,b){return a - b})[myArray.length-2];
alert(secondLargest); //120;
```

Comment: fails if smallest number is repeated multiple times lol

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function second_highest(arr)
{
  var second_highest = arr.sort(function(a, b) { return b - a; })[1];
  return second_highest;

}
```

Comment: Do note that sort will sort the original array, it won't make a copy. So anything relying on the previous ordering of the items may break.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getSecondLargest(nums) {
 return [...new Set(nums)].sort((a,b)=>b-a)[1]    
}
```

Comment: Has the merit of brevity. Care to comment on behaviour on arguments with no more than one distinct value, to compare to other "sort()-solutions" suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution using filter & reduce methods:

```
arr = [20,120,111,215,54,78];
const secondMax = arr
         .filter((ele)=> ele !== Math.max(...arr))
         .reduce((acc, ele) => ele > acc ? ele : acc , arr[0])
```

Comment: why not `Math.max(...arr.filter(x => x !== Math.max(...arr)))`?

Comment: This also works fine & looks a lot better.

Comment: and if you want to only use reduce: `arr.slice(2).reduce((x, y) => [...x, y].sort((a, b) => b - a).slice(0, 2), arr.slice(0, 2))[1]`

Comment: or `arr.slice(2).reduce((x, y) => y > x[0] ? [y, x[0]] : x[0] > y > x[1] ? [x[0], y] : x, arr.slice(0, 2).sort())[1]`

Answer (score 0):

```
let randomArr = [1,3,5,2,7,6,22,45,67,44];
let sortedArr = randomArr.sort( (a,b) => a-b); // sort array in ASC order
sortedArr.at(-2); // gives 2nd last item in array
```