# Select table cells with highest value/s and second highest value/s

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following table and need to find

- one or more **td** with the class "sum" with **highest value** (number)
- one or more **td** with the class "sum" with **second highest** value (number)
- add class "text-bold" to the matching tds

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odftqhd3/25/)
code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.text-bold { font-weight: 700; }
table {
    margin: 16px 0;
    color:#333;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #666;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table th {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #666;
    background-color: #FBDD9B;
}
table td {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #666;
    background-color: #fff;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="table-results">
        <tr>
            <th>Question</th>
            <th>inovation</th>
            <th>all-round</th>
            <th>coordination</th>
            <th>keeper</th>
            <th>analytic</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>I.</td>
            <td>D=2</td>
            <td>A=1</td>
            <td>E=10</td>
            <td>C=8</td>
            <td>B=4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>II.</td>
            <td>A=6</td>
            <td>C=1</td>
            <td>B=2</td>
            <td>D=5</td>
            <td>E=1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>III.</td>
            <td>E=4</td>
            <td>B=1</td>
            <td>D=3</td>
            <td>A=2</td>
            <td>C=7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Suma</td>
            <td class="sum">12</td>
            <td class="sum">3</td>
            <td class="sum">15</td>
            <td class="sum">15</td>
            <td class="sum">12</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

In the example above the result should look like this

Suma    **12**  3   **15**  **15**  **12**

Other possible results

Suma    0   0   0   **10**  0
Suma    **12**  3   **15**  7   9
Suma    1   3   **15**  **15**  **12**
Suma    **12**  3   **15**  9   **12**
Suma    **4**   **4**   **4**   **4**   **4**

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Your jsfiddle only has the HTML and CSS, no attempts

Comment: from where your data is coming. It can be done with js jq php bt not witsh css

Comment: You will need to loop it anyway to identify which columns have the 2 highest values. Now go write some code doing that ...

Comment: I edited the question. There was a mistake in the css and changed jsfiddle with the code I have so far, which finds only highest number

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Thanks all for the help and answers. I will read and try them later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually a little bit complicated, you have to get an array with the numbers from the `.sum` elements, then find the highest number, then remove all those from the array, then find the next highest number, and finally target all elements containing those two numbers.

In code, that would look like

```
var sum = $('.sum');
var arr = sum.map(function(_,x) { return +$(x).text() }).get();
var max = Math.max.apply( Math, arr );
var out = arr.filter(function(x) { return x != max });
var nxt = Math.max.apply( Math, out );

sum.filter(function() {
    var numb = +$(this).text();
    return numb == max || numb == nxt;
}).css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/odftqhd3/10/)

Comment: stupid question,what is the purpose of the '+' in front of $(x) and $(this)?

Comment: @JRulle - it just makes the string a number, not that it's really needed here, but just to make sure.

Comment: thanks, I seriously learned a lot breaking down your answer with some googling and playing with the fiddle you created... great answer

Answer (score 4):

Ok this take me a while. To find max number was kinda easy using the following code:

```
//declare a variable for max taking the value of first td
var max = $("#table-results tr:last td:eq(1)").text();    
//iterate through the last row of the table
$("#table-results tr:last td").each(function () {
    //get the value of each td
    var tdVal = ~~this.innerHTML;
    //compare the value with max value
    if (tdVal > max) {
        //change the font-weight when is max
        $(this).css("font-weight", "bold");
    }    
});
```

But the tricky part to find second max. I used code from @Jack answer from this question [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039770/how-do-i-get-the-second-largest-element-from-an-array-in-javascript/17040125#17040125) and ended up to this result:

```js
//declare a variable for max taking the value of first td
var max = $("#table-results tr:last td:eq(1)").text();
var arr = [];

//iterate through the last row of the table and keep the values in an array
$("#table-results tr:last td").each(function() {
  arr.push(~~this.innerHTML);
});

//get the second max from the array
var secMax = secondMax(arr);

//iterate through the last row of the table
$("#table-results tr:last td").each(function() {
  //get the value of each td
  var tdVal = ~~this.innerHTML;
  //compare the value with max value
  if (tdVal > max) {
    //change the font-weight when is max
    $(this).css("font-weight", "bold");
  }
  //comapre the second max value with the current one
  if (tdVal == secMax) {
    $(this).css("font-weight", "bold");
  }

});



function secondMax(arr) {
  ///with this function i find the second max value of the array
  biggest = -Infinity,
    next_biggest = -Infinity;

  for (var i = 0, n = arr.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var nr = +arr[i]; // convert to number first

    if (nr > biggest) {
      next_biggest = biggest; // save previous biggest value
      biggest = nr;
    } else if (nr < biggest && nr > next_biggest) {
      next_biggest = nr; // new second biggest value
    }
  }
  return next_biggest;
}
```

```css
.text-bold {
  text-weight: 700;
}
table {
  margin: 16px 0;
  color: #333;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #666;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table th {
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #666;
  background-color: #FBDD9B;
}
table td {
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #666;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table-results">
  <tr>
    <th>Question</th>
    <th>inovation</th>
    <th>all-round</th>
    <th>coordination</th>
    <th>keeper</th>
    <th>analytic</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>I.</td>
    <td>D=2</td>
    <td>A=1</td>
    <td>E=10</td>
    <td>C=8</td>
    <td>B=4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>II.</td>
    <td>A=6</td>
    <td>C=1</td>
    <td>B=2</td>
    <td>D=5</td>
    <td>E=1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>III.</td>
    <td>E=4</td>
    <td>B=1</td>
    <td>D=3</td>
    <td>A=2</td>
    <td>C=7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Suma</td>
    <td class="sum">12</td>
    <td class="sum">3</td>
    <td class="sum">15</td>
    <td class="sum">15</td>
    <td class="sum">12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have put together the following jQuery function to solve your problem. It iterates through the values, determines the largest and second largest values then applies the `text-bold' class to the relevant cells in the table [**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/odftqhd3/23/)

```
$(function(){
  //set initial values
    var largest = 0;
    var second = 0;
  //fetch the td elements with sum class
    var $sums = $('td.sum');
  //iterate through to find the values that represent largest and second
    $sums.each(function(){
      //set value of cell to variable for comparison (parsed to ensure it is a number)
        var value = parseInt($(this).text());
        if(largest == 0) { largest = value; }
        else if(value > largest) { 
            second = largest;
            largest = value;
        }
        else if(value == largest) {  }  //this prevents second from being overwritten by a duplicate largest value
        else if(value > second) { 
            second = value;
        }
        else {  }
    });
  //iterate through again bolding the largest and second largest values
  //had to use this method because values can exist more than once
    $sums.each(function(){
        if($(this).text() == largest || $(this).text() == second) {
            $(this).addClass("text-bold");
        }
    });
});
```

You also need to make a slight adjustment to your CSS. the `.text-bold` class should have `font-weight` not `text-weight` assigned.

```
.text-bold {
    font-weight: 700;
}
```